# Flex Mobile IconItemRenderer not garbage collected

Tags: apache-flex, memory, mobile, memory-leaks, itemrenderer

I have a list with ItemRenderers extending IconItemRenderer... I dispose the list when I come to a page and remove it when I leave...

In the profiler at the begining I have 1 List and 12 ItemRenderes... after a while there is still 1 list and the amount I visited the page * 12 ItemRenderes (4 visits, 48 ItemRenderers)

Any Idea how I can get them garbage collected? In The profiler I see nothing related to my code (ObjectReferences)...

The only hint for me is in IconItemRenderer:

```
private function attachLoadingListenersToIconDisplay():void
{
    if (iconDisplay)
    {
        iconDisplay.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, iconDisplay_loadErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
        iconDisplay.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, iconDisplay_loadErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
    }
}
```

and the listeners seem not to be removed...

Disposing the list...?

```
if(myList)
        {
            myList.dataProvider = null;
            if(contains(myList))
            {
                myList.parent.removeChild(myList);
            }
        }
        myList= null;
```

Anyone an idea

More info:

My ItemRenderer extends IconItemRenderer...

I have a UIComponent holding a list:

```
override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();

        ...

        myList= new List();
        myList.setStyle('contentBackgroundAlpha', 1);
        myList.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor', 0x333333);
        myList.setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", ScrollPolicy.OFF);
        myList.height = 6 * ROW_HEIGHT;
        myList.horizontalCenter = 0;
        myList.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyItemRenderer);
        addChild(myList);

        if(myList.layout && myList.layout is VerticalLayout)
        {
            VerticalLayout(myList.layout).variableRowHeight = false;
            VerticalLayout(myList.layout).gap = 1;
        }

    }
```

and disposing it:

```
public function dispose():void
    {

        ...

        if(myList)
        {
            myList.dataProvider = null;
            if(contains(myList))
            {
                removeChild(myList);
            }
        }
        myList= null;
    }
```

Comment: When is 'attachLoadingListenersToIconDisplay()' called?  Is it part of your renderer?  Is there code in the renderer to remove the event listeners?  If not; you may just pile event listeners on top of each other each time that method is called.  Where is the dispose list code called?  It strikes me as "off" to call 'parent.removeChild'

Comment: Following these steps helped me find dangling references that were preventing garbage collection:[solving memeory leaks](http://tikalk.com/flex/solving-memory-leaks-using-flash-builder-4-profiler)

Comment: Is iconDisplay part of the same Class that contains the methods that are being added to it as listeners? Is _that_ Class removed from the Display list?

Comment: added more code...

the function attachLoadingListenersToIconDisplay is in IconItemRenderer (FlexFramework-Code)

the list itself is removed from the display list

Comment: @NTyler... as above explained I end in attachLoadingListenersToIconDisplay of IconItemRenderer

Comment: Okay... stupid... found the problem... The ItemRenderer had an image as child which had registerd itself for updates in a Singleton... but this place I haven't seen anywhere in the profiler...

Comment: Thanks a lot ... now I just have to find a place to unregister them for updates (the Singleton holds references to all images which wanted to be updated..)

So thanks a lot for all your comments

Comment: Is there a place/function in the itemrenderer which gets called if the list is removed???